# Wordpress. favicon в виде головы робота

Tags: php, wordpress, favicon

На некоторых страницах фавикон выглядит так:  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоли нахожу прямую ссылку из uploads, перехожу по ней и фавикон тот, который нужен. Парадокс. То есть ссылку

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https:/MYSITE/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/favicon.ico">
```

открывает правильно, иконка верная.
В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Кеш браузера. попробуйте зайти из инкогнито или с другого браузера и проверьте наявность ошибки еще раз

Comment: @ВадимАлександру Не помогло(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Chrome есть проблема - если внутри тега `<head></head>` есть html-код (которого по правилам там быть не должно), и этот код выше, чем `<link rel="icon"...`, то иконку сайта вы не увидите. Вот простейший пример html-файла, где иконка не отображается.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <div>
        Some div.
    </div>
    <link rel="icon" href="http://test.test/cropped-admin-favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192" />
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

А вот тот же самый файл, который отобразит иконку:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="http://test.test/cropped-admin-favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192" />
    <div>
        Some div.
    </div>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Пример проверен на последней версии Chrome.

**TLDR**

1. Вам надо вашу иконку поднять выше в теге `<head></head>`. Как это сделать - нельзя сказать, не увидев вашего кода.
2. Где-то ещё выводится другая иконка `link rel="icon"` с головой робота, найдите её в коде страницы, и запретите её вывод. Возможно, выводит голову робота ваша тема.

Comment: Спасибо, это был плагин autoptimize с использвоанием сервиса shortpixel для изображений. Убрал, странно, что только на опредленных страницах срабатывал и добавлял свой фавикон.